# Authentication "pop-up" window breaks OHS->WebLogic proxy

Tags: http, weblogic

I have setup an app on WebLogic (11g) with OHS as the front end. The app is over SSL.

Scenario 1 : I deploy the app on WebLogic, setup OHS as reverse proxy and access it from a browser. Everything is good.

Scenario 2 : The app is modified to include authentication in the form of a "pop-up" window. Once I deploy this app on WebLogic, I cannot access it from OHS. I can access it via WebLogic but not OHS.

Thinking this is related to DynamicServerList, I turned it off, but it did not help.

Has anyone resolved this?

Comment: What error do you get when accessing the secured page via OHS. It is possible that you have not enabled 'WebLogic Plugin Enabled' attribute on the WLS side - you can find this in the WLS console.

Comment: Sorry for not responding earlier. I could solve this issue by enabling 'WebLogic plugin' on the WLS managed servers. I figured it out the hard way by comparing configuration between an environment where it worked and the one where it failed. Prash is 100% correct about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by enabling WebLogic plugin on the WLS managed servers.